# Retrieving the actual file from a http request (for os.stat)

Tags: django, python-3.x, http, serialization

I'd like to retrieve the meta  data of an uploaded file  by use of:

```
st = os.stat(file_path)
```

However I'm not sure how  to parse the file_path attribute from the http request. For example, I've used:

```
request.FILES
```

but then get:

```
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not MultiValueDict
```

I also serialize the request, like so:

```
serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
```

How do I get the actual uploaded file in  the http  reques?

Comment: Have you tried to inspect what is inside `request.FILES['file']`?

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts: yes and same error message I'm afraid

Comment: Specifically what information from `os.stat()` do you need?

Answer (score 2):

While it is questionable if this is proper thing to do in general *before__* file is saved to permanent location (it may not be applicable to cloud storage etc), answer is:

When uploaded file is *temporary* stored by Django either in memory (if small) or on disk with [upload handlers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers).

All [UploadedFiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/uploads/#uploaded-files) will have attributes like **size**, **name**.

If **TemporaryFileUploadHandler** was used to store file - this file in `request.FILES` will be [TemporaryUploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile) and will have `temporary_file_path()` method:

```
for f in request.FILES.getlist("file_field"):
    try:
        fstats = os.stat(f.temporary_file_path())
    except AttributeError:
        # do something
    # file processing logic
```

Comment: I think this partly answers the question. I just made some changes  in settings.py FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',], and got this to work. The problem is though the stat in os.stat take the new temp file path. So the "original" file meta data somehow gets lost (for example, I can't get the creation date, just the creation date from the new handler's  temp file path)

Comment: This metadata (creation / modification / access time, inodes, permissions, owner) is set by underlying filesystem and is not actual part of the data of file, rather a tag attached by filesystem to a file. During uploads only actual file data is transferred. Some / all of fs metadata may preserve with in archives. So, when user uploads file, there is no such metadata with file.

Comment: Ok I see, so if on a Windows machine then it's determined within the Windows file  system

Comment: Can't you get the required metadata as another http request? It would be much simpler to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the actual file from a http request you can use this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['XYZ']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        server_file_name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
```

where XYZ is the value of name attribute in the input tag. Like this:

```
<input type="file" name="XYZ" aria-label="Upload File" id="_upload_file">
```